# Mocha processes typescript files when it does not need too

Tags: typescript, webpack, mocha.js, typescript1.8, ts-loader

I am packing up all my tests with webpack so that I can deploy and run them in every environment that my app is hosted in.
How ever when I run the tests from a pure javascript file, the one webpack has made for me mocha still wants to process typescript files. I get the same behaviour when I run the test files that tsc has transpiled to js. Here's the stack trace. Please any help will be much appreciated.

```
λ npm run cm:test:build
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.6
npm info using node@v6.5.0
npm info lifecycle cs-card@1.0.0~precm:test:build: cs-card@1.0.0

> cs-card@1.0.0 precm:test:build C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card
> tsc

npm info lifecycle cs-card@1.0.0~cm:test:build: cs-card@1.0.0

> cs-card@1.0.0 cm:test:build C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card
> webpack --config test/webpack.config.js

ts-loader: Using typescript@1.8.10 and C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\tsconfig.json
Hash: a9dae0564433ba4614d5
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 3577ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
all.specs.js  6.11 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 6 hidden modules
npm info lifecycle cs-card@1.0.0~postcm:test:build: cs-card@1.0.0
npm info ok

C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card (master) (cs-card@1.0.0){hg}
λ mocha test/all.specs.js
C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\node_modules\cs-core\src\user.ts:3
import { Iuuid } from "./contracts/uuid";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\node_modules\cs-core\index.js:23:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\test\all.specs.js:176:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\test\all.specs.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\test\all.specs.js:95:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\test\all.specs.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\test\all.specs.js:49:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\test\all.specs.js:20:30)
    at C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\test\all.specs.js:40:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wmunt\Dropbox\cs-framework\projects\card\test\all.specs.js:43:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Users\wmunt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:219:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\wmunt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:216:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\wmunt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:468:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wmunt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:403:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

The webpack file I used

```
"use strict";
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");
var webpack_1 = require("webpack");
var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync("node_modules")
    .filter(function (x) {
    return [".bin"].indexOf(x) === -1;
})
    .forEach(function (mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = "commonjs " + mod;
});
var wepackConfig = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/components/card/server/models/card.model.spec.ts"),
    target: "node",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
        filename: "all.specs.js",
    },
    externals: nodeModules,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ["ts-loader"] }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack_1.DefinePlugin({
            Promise: require("es6-promise").Promise
        })
    ]
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = wepackConfig;
//# sourceMappingURL=webpack.config.js.map
```

and my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "declaration": false
  },
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".vscode",
    "report",
    "dist",
    "output"]
}
```